# My 2003 Nissan Altima makes noise

Tags: nissan, noise, altima

My 2003 Nissan Altima makes noise. It seems to me like there is something touches to a running fan. The noise starts as soon as I start driving and after 10-15 km the noise disappears. I know I need to change the brake pads and it does not seem that the noise comes from the worn pads as I heard such noise should stop when you hit brake. In my case the noise does not stop when I hit the brake.

One more thing to mention, the noise started after I changed the oil(Castrol) and the oil filter (mobil 1)
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Various Nissan models, and other vehicles, have an Extra Air Pump (EAP). When the engine is first started from cold the oxygen sensors are running cold and not up to operating temperature. To control any emissions whilst cold an EAP runs to pump air into the exhaust to help clean it up until the oxygen sensors are fully working, you may have a noisy pump. (Always worth a check over at a repair shop or with a mechanic to make sure though.)